# Generating a web site from xsn files

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, browser, infopath, chromium

As we all know, the infopath forms service residing on a sharepoint server generates a web site each time we publish an inforpath form template to the sharepoint server.

Here is the question: how does sharepoint do that. Is there any way for us to do that programmatically via some kind of api provided by MS?

In fact, what I need to do is getting all the html, js, css etc. files and applying some kind of operations like deleting some divs or insert some html code into the particular web page. I have come up with two ways to do this.

- Generating the web page via sharepoint api and apply those operations at the same time
- Extracting the web page files from the IIS server and apply those operations

I am totally new to this kind of work. All in my mind is that each time we right click on a web page in the browser and choose to save the web page, the browser gets some of the files we need to render the web page and makes it possible for us to browse the web page offline.

[httrack](http://www.httrack.com/)
[WinWSD](http://download.cnet.com/WinWSD-WebSite-Downloader/3000-2377_4-10562531.html)
and tools like that seems to work fine with extracting html files from online web pages but not that well with js, css files.

Now I am trying to dig into the chromium project for some kind of inspiration, although whether it helps or not is unpredictable.

Any kind of advice will be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Jordan

Answer (score 1):

Infopath xsn files are just zip files with a different extension.  you can rename the extension to .zip and extract out the files.  you will find a number of files that make up the form.  the two main ones are the .xml and .xsl files.  the .xsl will have the html to generate when applied to the xml.